# replaceWith doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to replace current tag if the ajax response is success

```
$('.glyphicon-eye-close').click(function() {
          var v = this.id;
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'hide.html',
              data: { 
                  bookId: v ,
              },
              success: function(response) {
                  if (response == 'success') {
                      $(this).replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

But it doesn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work because the context in the event handler is wrong.

Comment: What is being returned from hide.html? Are you explicitly returning a "success" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope of `$(this)` do not exist in success function. you can use previously store id value in variable `v` to use it as selector:

```
$('#'+v).replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
```

Additionally, defined click handler wont work for dynamically added element(with repalceWith() in your case). you would need event delegation to make the click handler work on them.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('click','.glyphicon-eye-close',function() {
   //rest code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what $(this) is in your Success callback? I'm betting it's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

using `$(this)` reference of element will not be avaiable in ajax context, store reference of element in a variable outside ajax call and use variable inside ajax:

```
var element = $(this);
```

and then:

```
element.replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
```

do like this:

```
$('.glyphicon-eye-close').click(function() {
          var element = $(this);
          var v = this.id;
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'hide.html',
              data: { 
                  bookId: v ,
              },
              success: function(response) {
                  if (response == 'success') {
                      element.replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case this points to ajax object
Try to define context.

```
$('.glyphicon-eye-close').click(function() {
          var v = this.id;
          var self = this;
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'hide.html',
              data: { 
                  bookId: v ,
              },
              success: function(response) {
                  if (response == 'success') {
                      $(self).replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option on `$.ajax` for that:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, //<< Here, set context of any callback method
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'hide.html',
    data: {
        bookId: v,
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 'success') {
            $(this).replaceWith('<span id="' + v + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
        }
    }
});
```

### --DOC--

> ***context*** Type: PlainObject This object will be made the context of all
>   Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that
>   represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged
>   with the settings passed to $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM
>   element as the context will make that the context for the complete
>   callback of a request

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with scope. $(this) in your case is 'success' function. Try to use `var me = this` at the begining and then use `me` instead of this

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the context of the ajax callbacks within your ajax() parameters.

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  type: 'GET', //etc...
```

Also you need to be sure that your ajax URL is indeed returning a "success" value. If you're expecting the status of the ajax request you need to define the second parameter of the success callback function and run your conditional against that instead. You can verify by using console.log() like this:

```
success: function(response) {
  console.log(repsonse);
  if (response == 'success') {//etc...
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ECQU3/